# Me devuelve un cero adicional en Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Estoy realizando una consulta en donde me va a mostrar la cantidad de personas en un encuentro utilizando *Ajax*, *PHP* y *Json*. **El inconveniente que estoy teniendo es que la respuesta que estoy obteniendo me agrega un cero de mas**. En este caso la consulta *SQL* me devuelve un 3 pero en *Javascript* se **agrega un cero** pero no se de donde.  De ente mano , muchas gracias por la atencion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la funcion en javascript

```
function buscarParticipantesPorPuja(id_partido){
               
            $.ajax({
                url:  ajax_var.url,
                type: 'post', 
                data: {
                    action: 'lm_buscarParticipantesPorPuja',
                    id_partido: id_partido,
                   
                }, 
                success: function(respuesta){
                    console.log( '.md_partido_participantes: ' + respuesta );
                    $('.md_partido_participantes').html('Participantes: ' + respuesta );
                }
            }); 
        }
```

y esta es la funcion en PHP

```
function lm_buscarParticipantesPorPuja(){
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'id_partido' ] ) ):
        $id = esc_html( $_POST[ 'id_partido' ] ) ;
        global $wpdb;
        $nombreTabla = $wpdb->prefix . "apuestas";
        $query_id = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT(*) as cuenta 
                                        FROM $nombreTabla
                                        WHERE encuentro =  $id
                                        
                                        ", OBJECT );
        
        $cuenta = '';
        foreach($query_id as $q):
            $cuenta = $q->cuenta;
        endforeach;
        

        echo 'Participantes PHP: '.$cuenta;
    else:
        $cuenta = 0;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: antes de que el dato llegue a javascript de regreso, en PHP `$cuenta` tiene el dato con o sin el cero?

Comment: En $cuenta en llega el dato sin cero.

Comment: Me suena que está imprimendo el código de status. Yo probaría agregando los dos parámetros más que lleva la función del success.

Comment: ¿Esta consulta está supuesta a devolver varias filas? Parecería que sólo se necesita una sola fila, entonces ¿por qué usas un bucle para leer los resultados? El `0` puede estar saliendo de cualquier parte, por tanto sugiero que depures los datos, por ejemplo: `var_dump($cuenta);` te ayudará a descartar que el `0` no se agrega en la variable final. Y si esperas una sola fila, evita el bucle.